# Using bootstrap-datepicker in Yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, yii2

I've installed bootstrap-datepicker using composer on my Yii2 project. Javascript still won't understand 'datepicker' command. Is there anything else I have to do to require this library? Maybe use 'use eternicode/...' command in a view file? Even though can't find out a proper way they form after being installed via composer.

Here's the link to github of this library: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Where is this js code ? How do you register it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `AssetBundle` so it can be registered by a `View`.

```
<?php
    namespace app\assets;

    use yii\web\AssetBundle;

    class DatepickerAsset extends AssetBundle 
    {
        public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap-datepicker/dist';
        public $js = ['js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'];
        public $css = ['css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css'];
    }
```

The above is an example as I don't know what folders will be created by composer.

Then in the view,

```
<?php
    DatepickerAsset::register($this);
```

This will insert the necessary script and css tags into the output.

[Full Docs here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html)

Comment: Thank you @Alex, but "Class 'app\assets\DatepickerAsset' not found"

Comment: My mistake. Had to create new Asset instead of adding class in the default one.

Comment: I still get the "$(...).datepaginator is not a function" error

Comment: Have you created the asset bundle? Have you registered it in the view?

Comment: solved everything. I actually did not download datepaginator.js due to absence of instructions in plugin module. Thougth the script would use bootstrap's own functionality. Thank you.